# Is it possible to install an Ad Hoc build to Jailbroken iPhone without adding that iPhone to Device List?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, jailbreak, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an iOS **App**, **Device1** and **Device2**.
**Ad Hoc** distribution is used for the App, Device1 is added to Device List, and Device2 isn't. So I can build App with Xcode and install it to Device1, but not to Device2.

Now let's say I jailbreak Device2. The question is if I can somehow install the App's dev build to Device2 without adding it to Ad Hoc Device List.

1. Can we install the app onto JB device if device UUID not added to Provisioning profile? If yes, does it depend on the JB provider (e.g. `checkra1n`), Xcode version (`12.5`/`13`), iOS version (`15`/`15.2`)?
2. Is this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5277410/2567725) still valid?

*I know nothing about Jailbreak, want to try it to improve my undestanding of some things. Googled a lot about this question, and still not sure if it's possible to do what I want. But if the device is JB, it should give much more debugging power, so I believe there should exist some workaround!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jailbreaks will allow such apps to run, but they do not usually patch the installation daemon.
For that, you want [AppSync Unified](https://cydia.akemi.ai/?page/net.angelxwind.appsyncunified).